# GDB: nested conditional breakpoints

Tags: debugging, gdb

is it possible to have nested conditional breakpoints in GDB?
I would like to have a conditional similar to the code below. Also, I do not want to AND or OR conditionals together, I want them to be nested.

```
if(obj.people == true){
      if(obj.age == 24){
      }
}
```

at the moment I am only able to break on a single conditional (see below).

```
cond 1 inst->isLoad() == true
```

Comment: "I want them to be nested." -- nested condition is _exactly_ equivalent to _AND_. What are you _really_ trying to achieve?

Comment: The object  (inst)  I am dealing with is not always the same sometimes; it is a Load instruction, an add instruction, or a jump instruction. Each object is different because they have unique functions and variables that each can access. So If I want to analyze a load instruction, I want first to make sure the instruction is a load and then use the other nested conditional to check whether the unique variables associated with it have met the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

> I want first to make sure the instruction is a load and then use the other nested conditional to check whether the unique variables associated with it have met the criteria.

That is *exactly* what AND does. If you write a condition like so:

```
   cond 1 inst->isLoad() && inst->otherCondition()
```

then, due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), the `otherCondition()` will *only* be evaluated if `isLoad()` condition is true.

Comment: I did not know that! Thank you